# How to use dynamic roles with @TestSecurity

Tags: automated-tests, quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I would like to use **dynamic roles** in my @TestSecurity annotation.

My resource:

```
    @Path("/web-app")
    @Authenticated
    public class MyProtectedResource{

        @GET
        @Path("my-path") 
        @RolesAllowed({ "admin", "user" }) 
        public String getSomething() {
            // return something;
        }    
    }
```

So instead of doing this (which works fine):

```
@QuarkusTest
@TestHTTPEndpoint(MyProtectedResource.class)
public class TestMyProtectedResource{

    @Test
    @TestSecurity(user = "testUser", roles = { "admin" })
    public void myTest() {
        // Some test
    }

}
```

I would like to do this:

```
@QuarkusTest
@TestHTTPEndpoint(MyProtectedResource.class)
public class TestMyProtectedResource{

    private String[] allRoles = ["admin", "user"] 

    @Test
    @TestSecurity(user = "testUser", roles = allRoles )
    public void myTest() {
        // Some test
    }    
}
```

but the roles attribute needs to be a constant. Is there another way of doing this? **Ideally I would like to run the same test multiple times with different sets of roles**.

Otherwise I would have to duplicate quite a bit of code to test all interesting role combinations